# Is uTouch still in use or under development?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, multi-touch

I have not been hearing or seeing much regarding uTouch, and with the recent developments regarding Ubuntu Touch, I've been wondering, is uTouch still used in Ubuntu (as in will it be a part of the platform going forward), and is it still being developed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an answer from [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/geis/+question/211763):

> The software that formerly made up the utouch project is now a part of the Ubuntu core so we no longer have need of a separate 'utouch' package. The individual components are still available and have simply been renamed without the 'utouch-' component.